# Kotlin @FunctionalInterface compiles with multiple abstract methods

Tags: kotlin, functional-interface

When trying to compile a Java `@FunctionalInterface` having more than 1 non-abstract method a compilation error is raised.

However, when doing the same in Kotlin, no errors or warnings are raised, i.e. the following Kotlin `interface` compiles successfully:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Foo {
    fun foo()
    fun foo(params: Map<String, String>)
}
```

Is this the intended behaviour or a bug in the Kotlin compiler?

Please note that the generated bytecode for the above Kotlin snippet is equivalent to the following Java snippet (which – correctly – doesn't compile):

```
@FunctionalInterface
// metadata omitted
public interface Foo {
   void foo();
   void foo(@NotNull Map var1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue [KT-25512](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25512) has been submitted to JetBrains's issue tracker (by another user) to report the fact that the compiler misbehaves when `@FunctionalInterface` is applied to a non-SAM interface, and as of 10 Feb 2019 the issue is still open with no activity.

### EDIT

Not really like for like, but starting from Kotlin 1.4 the language defines a [new syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces) for defining functional interfaces:

```kotlin
fun interface Foo {
    fun foo()
}
```

The compiler will complain if a `fun interface` isn't a functional interface:

```kotlin
fun interface Foo {
    fun foo()
    fun anotherFoo()
}
```

gives an error:

```
Fun interfaces must have exactly one abstract method
```